# I am not able to create test for given code in pycharm. Is anyone can help me for this?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver= webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.dsvv.ac.in/")

scroll_link= driver.find_element_by_link_text("Skill Development Workshops (CCAM) 2017-18")

scroll_link.click()

driver.close()
```

Actually want to get test results for this code in pycharm...But I can't found the option "Go to | Test" on the context menu for this code.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do, and what the problem is?

Comment: Actually want to get test results for this code in pycharm...But I can't found the option "Go to | Test" on the context menu for this code. So I am not able to create test ?

Comment: Not sure what the bigger picture here is or if you are approaching this in the correct way, however for the context menu question see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Please note that this only answers the question "why won't PyCharm let me create tests for my code with the context menu".*

PyCharm will offer the "Go to | Test" context menu option when you are clicking inside something it deems suitable to create tests for, or tests already exist.

That could be a class or a function for example.

Your code doesn't contain anything PyCharm will recognize as candidate to create a test for, so it doesn't show the option.

Try to modify your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def selfun():

    driver= webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("http://www.dsvv.ac.in/")

    scroll_link= driver.find_element_by_link_text("Skill Development Workshops (CCAM) 2017-18")

    scroll_link.click()

    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    selfun()
```

Click on (or somewhere inside) the `selfun` function, and PyCharm will offer to create a test when you select "Go to | Test".